# Почему глобальные переменные это зло, а поля класса нет?

Tags: ооп, область-видимости

Я знаю про побочные эффекты. Меня интересует не почему глобальные переменные - это в принципе плохо, а почему постоянно говорят, что они зло, хотя про поля класса я такого не слышал никогда. 
Хотя, по сути, поля класса ведь ничем не отличаются? Это такие же глобальные переменные, только в пределах класса.

Comment: Ну разница-то есть.. среди одного класса или среди сотен классов........ одно дело в твоей квартире можешь проживать ты, а другое - все люди планеты земля

Comment: Говорят, то они зло, потому что они зло ). Не называть же зло добром.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, возможно у меня просто опыта в структурном программировании маловато. Но, например, в C++, если объявить глобальные переменные не в заголовочном файле, то они будут доступны только внутри того файла, в котором их объявили.

Comment: Так постоянно говорят те, кто не занимался параллельным программированием, где без глобальных переменных, вообще говоря, не получится передать сообщение между узлами. Вообще, это стереотип такой. Такой же как то, будто goto - это зло. Догма, распространяемая неопытными программистами или теми программистами, которые за пределами своей узкой сферы ничего не знают. Причина в том, что **неумелое** использование глобальных переменных - зло. А **умелое** мало где найдешь. В этом и разгадка вопроса.

Comment: @АртёмКараваев  вы меня щас в такую группу записали ) Если у паттерна/инструмента есть побочные эффекты, из-за которых паттерн нужно избегать, то это плохой паттерн. Его, конечно, можно использовать, особенно неумелым программистам, но от этого он разумным решением не станет. Допустимым решением - да, но разумным - нет. В шарпе вот нет глобалов и ничуть не мешает писать параллельно даже не используя статические переменные ( по сути эквивалент глобалов)

Comment: /me *взял попкорн*

Comment: @АртёмКараваев все докумены по параллельному процессингу, которые я видел, говорят одно и то же - не лезьте во внешний мир и не используйте состояние.

Comment: Ребята, когда попробуете разработать свой инструмент (например, компилятор), в котором есть функции работы с параллельными потоками, тогда мы сможем продолжить разговор. А пока я не вижу в этом смысла, я лишь поделился своим личным мнением. Сам я против глобальных переменных в обычном коде по причине того, что за ними трудно следить и с ними легко наделать ошибок, когда с кодом работает несколько человек. Всё :)

Comment: На самом деле @АртёмКараваев дело говорит. Например -- сюрприз-сюрприз -- некоторые классные фичи в Шарпике в реализации активно используют `goto`. И что ж теперь, программистам MS застрелиться? Другой вопрос, что это все такие вещи, о которых начинающих программистам лучше говорить, что их лучше не использовать. Ибо как известно сперва учатся соблюдать правила, а потом учатся, когда правила можно нарушать. Так и с этими вещами -- понимание придет с опытом.

Comment: @andreycha, совершенно верно. Для того, чтобы работать "по накатанной" дорожке, писанной кровью миллионов программистов и не наступать на типичные грабли, нужно соблюдать правила. Но иногда в профессиональной сфере возникают задачи, в которых правила нужно нарушать. Но делать это должен опытный человек, которые знает суть того, что делает. Поэтому слово "зло" - это именно зло для большинства обычных программистов в их привычной среде обитания. Соблюдая осторожность, зло можно укротить.

Comment: @АртёмКараваев каждый программист считает "не я же не обычный программист, я лучше среднего, мне можно делать глобальный изменяемый стейт, не то что этим джуниорам"...

Comment: @PashaPash, все зависит от дисциплины проекта и его архитектуры. Например, в emacs полно глобальных переменных, но вряд ли кто скажет, что он ... (напишите все, что думаете о глобальных переменных) / Хотя сам я уже не помню, когда последний раз их использовал (static в файле -- бывает).

Comment: [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Answer (score 20):

1. Глобальные переменные в большинстве случаев нарушают инкапсуляцию. К
   ним открыт неконтролируемый доступ отовсюду.
2. В большом проекте при обилии глобальных переменных возникает путаница в именах. Глобальную переменную же видно отовсюду, надо, чтобы отовсюду было понятно, зачем она.
3. Глобальные переменные в большинстве случаев нарушают принцип инверсии зависимостей (или делают возможным его нарушение).
4. Глобальные переменные ухудшают масштабируемость проекта.
5. Глобальные переменные ухудшают читаемость кода (в каком-то конкретно взятом месте непонятно, нужна ли какая-то конкретная глобальная переменная, или нет).
6. Глобальные переменные приводят к трудноуловимым ошибкам. Примеры: нежелательное изменение её значения в другом месте/другим потоком, ошибочное использование глобальной переменной для промежуточных вычислений из-за совпадения имен, возвращение функцией неправильного значения при тех же параметрах (оказывается, она зависима от глобальной переменной, а ее кто-то поменял).
7. Глобальные переменные создают большие сложности при использовании модульного тестирования.
8. Глобальные переменные увеличивают число прямых и косвенных связей в системе, делая её поведение труднопредсказуемым, а её саму - сложной для понимания и развития.

---

> Поля - это такие же глобальные переменные, только в пределах класса.

А давайте одежду дома складывать прямо на пол в любом месте квартиры: ведь 30 кв. см ящика в комоде - это те же 30 кв. см поверхности, что и на полу, только в пределах ящика. И гаражи для машин не нужны, можно на улице ставить. Надеюсь, аналогия понятна.
Ключевая ошибка в утверждении автора заключается в том, что поля класса никаким образом не являются глобальными - они принадлежат **объекту (экземпляру)** класса, если они не статические. У одного объекта - одни значения, у другого - другие. А статические поля класса общие для всех экземпляров, и это чаще всего тоже не очень хорошо.