# gunicorn с несколькими процессами: запустить directory cleaner фоновый поток только раз

Tags: python, gunicorn, mutex

У меня есть приложение, которое запускает демона таким образом:

```
directory_cleaner = DirectoryCleaner()
directory_cleaner.daemon = True
directory_cleaner.start()
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске моего проложения `gunicorn`'ом, я получаю множество процессов с множеством демонов. Есть какая-нибудь возможность передать в `gunicorn` информацию о том, какой из процессов должен запускать демона в отдельном потоке, в то время как остальные процессы этого делать не должны ?

Может есть другие способы ? Запускать отдельные скрипты `cron`'ом тоже не хочется. Я хочу сохранить единую точку запуска для всей программы.

Comment: Ох, и до сих пор никто даже комментария не написал? На мой взгляд, демона надо запускать отдельно от gunicorn'а одновременно с ним, а когда уже надо провести какие-то работы, то тогда уже отправлять демону команду любым доступным способом (если по расписанию, то лучше всё-таки cron, ибо gunicorn для этого не предназначен)

Comment: Я просто не хочу, чтобы программа рассыпалась по кускам. Какая-то часть запускается `cron`'ом, какая-то `supervisоrd`'ом, `gunicorn`ом и т.д. Хочеть нажать `run`, чтобы все было готово и все.  :)

Comment: Тогда отказывайесь от gunicorn :) Ну или запускайте и его, и демон отдельным специальным скриптом с этим самым run

Comment: Неужели безысходность ? ;(

Comment: формально вы можете ваш поток в чём-нибудь типа: [`on_starting()` запустить](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-hooks), но как @andreymal порекомендовал, вместо gunicorn, лучше другие средства для оркестровки не worker процессов использовать. Связанный вопрос: [Gunicorn with multiple workers: Is there an easy way to execute certain code only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24101724/4279)

Comment: А чем лучше ? Мне кажется, что `on_starting` отличный вариант, разве нет ?

Comment: потому что это не ответственность gunicorn следить за cleaner (это работа для что-нибудь вроде cron/supervisord/systemd/[circus](http://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#how-does-circus-stack-compare-to-a-classical-stack)), и работа cleaner в том же процессе может мешать обычной функциональности (из-за GIL). У вас всё равно  ещё вероятно nginx,база данных присутствуют.

Comment: @jfs не, у меня только маленькая виртуалка с маленьким сервером. `nginx` и база на других серверах. Не понимаю как `GIL` может помешать демону раз в сутки проверять папки и удалять старые...

Comment: Чтобы раз в сутки запустить питон скрипт, можно в cron прописать¶ можно учиться на чужих ошибках, можно на своих, можно вообще не учиться—для эксперимента можете ничего не менять (оставить on_starting()), а через полгодика посмотреть какие у вас проблемы были с веб-приложением, как вы их решали. Если надёжность, производительность не особо важны в вашем случае, то можно оставить первую опцию, которая работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50465/discussion-between-faoxis-and-jfs).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101724/gunicorn-with-multiple-workers-is-there-an-easy-way-to-execute-certain-code-onl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно где-то хранить состояние демона, а также предпринимать меры от запуска демона несколькими процессами одновременно.

Ситуация осложняется тем что внутри самого `gunicorn` нет примитивов для решения этой задачи. Значит вам нужно в каждом процессе обращаться к какому-то стороннему сервису чтобы узнать запущен демон чистки или нет. Если демон не запущен, то ответственному процессу нужно защитить от записи некое хранилище состояние демона (например, [с помощью flock](https://github.com/derpston/python-simpleflock)), а затем запустить демон очистки, дождаться успешного запуска, записать состояние в [глобальную переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510910/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82/511107), разблокировать.

```
import simpleflock

with simpleflock.SimpleFlock("/tmp/dircleaner"):
   # Запускаем демона
   # Отмечаем в файле или в БД что демон запущен
   pass
```

В худшем случае вы, фактически, в одной части программы, ограничите себя выполнением только в один поток на время запуска демона. Это означает что *все* процессы на сервере будут ждать одного пока тот не отчитается об успешном запуске демона. Бонусом к такому решению идут различные варианты race condition и прочие гейзенбаги.

Кроме того вам где-то нужно отслеживать корректную работу демона чистки. Что если он упадет с ошибкой оттого что на диске закончилось место под логи? Что если процесс-родитель погибнет жертвой [OOM Killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer)? Что если ...? Это целая отдельная проблема, которую знают как и умеют решать такие программы как Supervisor.

Так ли нужно забивать отверткой гвозди - решать вам.