# Сериализация списка словарей для memcached

Tags: python, python-3.x, memcached

Есть такой вот список словарей:

> [{'insp': 4816}, {'insp': 3252}, {'insp': 7107}, {'insp':
>   5948}, {'insp': 5257}, {'insp': 5916}, {'insp': 1673},
>   {'insp': 5503}, {'insp': 6030}, {'insp': 6439}, {'insp':
>   7151}, {'insp': 2411}, {'insp': 2208}, {'insp': 5010},
>   {'insp': 9978}, {'insp': 5613}, {'insp': 2634}, {'insp':
>   2308}, {'insp': 4711}, {'insp': 5050}, {'insp': 7721}]

Мне надо грамотно перевести его в строку, чтобы потом сериализовать ее для `memcached`. Как это сделать ? И как потом десериализовать ее ?

Пробовал `str(mylist)`, но в итоге после десериализации библиотекой pymemcache я получаю строку, в которой остается множество ненужных символов, типа `b` и `\`...

Comment: Для memcached? Известные мне библиотеки для работы с ним вроде сериализуют всё самостоятельно, не?

Comment: В частности, [python-memcached](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/1.53) автоматически использует pickle для сериализации

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример ? У меня никак не получается без дополнительных манипуляций запихнуть список словарей в `client.set()` и легко вернуть его через `client.get()`... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании клиента, укажите `serializer`, `deserializer` параметры [как это показано в документации](https://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#serialization). Пример показывает `json_serializer`, `json_deserializer`. Можно также использовать функции из `pymemcache.serde`, которые вызывают pickle.

Comment: Я пробовал сделать по примеру функций из документации. При десериализации возникается ошибка: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`.  А вот на `pymemcache.serde` я не обратил внимание в доке. Все заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @faoxis 1- если пример из документации не работает с соответствующей версией библиотеки, то [можно открыть issue на GitHub](https://github.com/pinterest/pymemcache/issues)  2- если самостоятельно не удаётся примером воспользоваться, то можно отдельный SO вопрос задать.

Comment: А не могли бы вы ответить на такой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604313/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-c-gunicorn ?