# Объявление переменных вне main функции

Tags: c

Правильно ли объявлять переменные вне main функции? Я хочу сделать это, для того чтобы мои переменные были глобальными, но правильно ли такое решение? Есть ли какие-то подводные камни?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Глобальные переменные в большинстве случаев нарушают инкапсуляцию. К ним открыт неконтролируемый доступ отовсюду.
> 2. В большом проекте при обилии глобальных переменных возникает путаница в именах. Глобальную переменную же видно отовсюду, надо,
>      чтобы отовсюду было понятно, зачем она.
> 3. Глобальные переменные в большинстве случаев нарушают принцип инверсии зависимостей (или делают возможным его нарушение).
> 4. Глобальные переменные ухудшают масштабируемость проекта.
> 5. Глобальные переменные ухудшают читаемость кода (в каком-то конкретно взятом месте непонятно, нужна ли какая-то конкретная
>      глобальная переменная, или нет).
> 6. Глобальные переменные приводят к трудноуловимым ошибкам. Примеры: нежелательное изменение её значения в другом месте/другим потоком,
>      ошибочное использование глобальной переменной для промежуточных
>      вычислений из-за совпадения имен, возвращение функцией неправильного
>      значения при тех же параметрах (оказывается, она зависима от
>      глобальной переменной, а ее кто-то поменял).
> 7. Глобальные переменные создают большие сложности при использовании модульного тестирования.
> 8. Глобальные переменные увеличивают число прямых и косвенных связей в системе, делая её поведение труднопредсказуемым, а её саму - сложной
>      для понимания и развития.

Из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511107/204271).